# Will Flydubai check your luggage through an Emirates flight on separate tickets?

Tags: luggage, emirates, dxb, flydubai

I have two separate tickets - one on Flydubai to Terminal 3 and then another one from the same terminal on Emirates. Will Flydubai agree to check my luggage through to Emirates? The [Emirates pages on Flydubai partnership](https://www.emirates.com/us/english/travel-partners/flydubai/) says its possible on a single ticket, but what about separate tickets?

If it matters the FlyDubai flight is FZ1942 and the Emirates flight is EK229.

Update: called FlyDubai, they said they can check the bag all the way through. Will add an answer once I actually complete the flight.

Comment: Do they at least sell that connection as a single ticket? Does it meet their MCT?

Comment: @jcaron yes they do, though it was $600 more expensive that way. The time between flights is 3 hours.

Comment: If they sell it for such a higher price I doubt they would offer the same service for the cheaper price. In normal operations it’s probably cheaper for them to check you through. The issue comes when there are any disruptions and the associated responsibility they take on, explicitly when selling the through ticket, probably implicitly when checking you through. You can always ask at check-in (airlines policies are inconsistent in that respect, and it may depend a lot on the fare and you status), but I’m not sure you can count on it.

Comment: @jcaron booked the Marhaba luggage transfer service just in case but will report back on this in a few weeks as I’ll try to check it all the way through

Comment: Highly unlikely.
It's difficult to do, since the baggage needs to be associated with a booking number. You can't really do this, if there are two different numbers.

Comment: @Hilmar called Flydubai, their agent seemed sure that I can do it. Also emailed them to get this in writing just in case. Will report later if they actually honor their promise...

Comment: I wonder who pays for ground handling. I mean, check-through means the airport facility handles the bag, which normally means automated barcode-scanning conveyor belts will simply reroute your bag to the loading area without human effort. When you buy a single ticket, the airline you are traveling with is charged for the service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they will! The trip ended up with hand luggage only in the end as I didn't pack as many stuff as expected but when asked at the Flydubai check-in counter it was confirmed that they can check luggage through on an Emirates ticket. The Emirates connection desk likewise confirmed its possible when handing out the boarding pass. Finally I've called Flydubai a few days before the flight and the operator confirmed this is possible free of charge.

So the answer is: **yes**, they'll do it. If somehow you encounter an unhelpful agent who refuses to do so, dnata (the local luggage management company) will do it for [around 90 USD](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168567/how-much-is-the-dnata-luggage-transfer-fee-at-dubai-airport).