# How much is the Dnata luggage transfer fee at Dubai airport?

Tags: dxb, flydubai

The [FlyDubai page](https://www.flydubai.com/en/destinations/connections) on transfers states the following:

> If your baggage is not tagged through to your final destination or if you’re travelling with an airline with which flydubai does not have an interline agreement, you’ll need to pay a baggage transfer fee to dnata.

How much is this fee for transferring luggage from a FlyDubai flight to an Emirates flight?

Comment: [Their website](https://www.marhabaservices.com/ae/english/transfer-service) (dnata brands the service "Marhaba services") is excruciatingly vague, though [this forum post](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/emirates-skywards/2043840-feedback-marhaba-service-tag-checked-bag-next-destination-separate-ticket.html) says the cost is on the order of 330 AED. It seems like you may need to call to actually purchase the baggage identification and tagging service, so its not clear to me that there's a publicly listed price for it.

Comment: @ZachLipton I’ve actually booked Marhaba at first but then their agent replies saying they don’t do luggage transfer for FlyDubai flights. So this is a slightly different service provider.

Comment: Fly Dubai and Emirates certainly do interline and they even have the same rewards program. It would be highly unusual that your  bags wouldn't get tagged through if you buy a single ticket.  Why do you think you need to pay extra ?

Comment: @Hilmar two separate tickets, already purchased (difference was $600 so worth it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Their website](https://www.marhabaservices.com/ae/english/transfer-service) (dnata brands the service "Marhaba services") is excruciatingly vague, though [this forum post](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/emirates-skywards/2043840-feedback-marhaba-service-tag-checked-bag-next-destination-separate-ticket.html) says the cost is on the order of 330 AED. So expect to pay around **90 USD** for this service.

We also have a [post on Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/57400/9009) mentioning this service cost 84 USD in 2015 so the Flyertalk forum post looks accurate.